# How to determine maximum number of included columns for SQL Server index or rely on lookups

Tags: sql-server, indexing

I have a SQL Server 2014 database where I need to page through a very large amount of data to feed a webservice. The problem I currently have is there are 2 indexes on this table that got created, one of them has 79 included columns and the other has 80. Both indexes are 9+GB and both are very similar but different queries use them. Looking at the data my webservice actually needs it looks like around 60 columns from the database.

So I want to kill these 2 indexes and create a single index that will serve both of these queries.

I believe I have 2 options:

1. Create an index that includes these 60 columns - which I know is super large and can slow things down and cause bloat.

OR

2. Create an index that does not include these columns but then causes lookups to get the needed column data.

I am having a hard time determining which of these is a better approach.

Comment: Sounds like some normalization would be more helpful. From what you describe you have at least 160 columns in your table?

Comment: no, I have 82 columns in my table and it is nomalized - the 79 columns, 80 columns are all overlapping so it is completely wasteful and needs addressing

Comment: OK, reading your question it sounded like you have more than double that. Do you really need all those columns in your index? Are you really joining or filtering on nearly every column in the table?

Comment: no I am not, I am filtering on 6 columns but the query selects from 60 columns

Comment: You don't need to create an index for every column in a select statement. You should be able to create a covering index on just those 6. You should read up on how to best create your indexing strategy. This is an awesome series on this topic. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72399/

Comment: @SeanLange I don't believe Slee is considering Indexing all 60 columns, I think he means to use the INCLUDE clause to avoid lookups.

Comment: I understand, I have just been reading on having included columns so you can avoid lookups - so my question was which is a better strategy.  An index that includes all of the columns you need or just rely on lookups for the needed column data.

Comment: @Slee frankly, since this is just an A/B comparison, and not a choice between 60 different possible options, I'd test them both and see.  There's no "conventional wisdom" I'm aware of regarding how many INCLUDE columns you should have.

Comment: Ahh I was not understanding what you were saying. Thanks to both of you for clarifying. I agree with @TabAlleman, just test both and see which one is better for you.

Comment: Sounds like a classic *space-vs-speed* trade-off; an index with 60+ included columns definitely adds a lot of additional disk space - but could be faster. No way of telling other than really trying yourself, with your data and your application.

Comment: In addition to the previous comments also things like how many rows are in the table, how many of them does your select fetch, what are the data types, how often the rows are inserted / updated / deleted etc. affect so it's really not possible just to give an answer which is better without testing things with the actual data.